# How to interact with Ubuntu through voice command (mic)?

Tags: 11.10, command-line, microphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Voice control over desktop enviornment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63743/voice-control-over-desktop-enviornment)

i want to know how to deal with Ubuntu using voice command (e.g. open home to open my home folder & minimize & maximize), is there any program can do it ???
it mean i can speak to the computer and it speak to me