# speech recognition on ubuntu server, what are my options?

Tags: command-line, speech-recognition, arduino

I want my ubuntu server to start playing music when I say the command, just like on iphone... "play [album]" "play [song]" etc.

I also want it to turn on light on my arduino project.

So to achieve this, I either need something already done, or I need to write something myself.

obviously, speech recognition software exists, I found few that seems solid: julious, sphinx.

Any help appreciated with this home server project.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/63743/voice-control-over-desktop-enviornment

Comment: I dont have gnome, this is ubuntu server.-

Comment: What kind of GUI are you using, if any at all?

Comment: No GUI. Ubuntu server, SSH power :X