# How do I install and use voice commands?

Tags: gnome, bash, microphone

How can I give my own command using mic.

I would like to give command like: "**Update system now**"

So system will automatic run apt-get update

I've seen [**Gnome Voice
   Control**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63743/voice-control-over-desktop-enviornment)

but I get error :

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-voice-control
[sudo] password for r00t: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gnome-voice-control
```

My Details:

```
$ uname -a
Linux penreturns 3.4.1-030401-generic #201206041411 SMP Mon Jun 4 18:12:24 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04 
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS" 
$ gnome-shell --version 
GNOME Shell 3.5.4
```

How do I start this project. What package do I need. What script do I need to learn.

Answer (score 8):

#### Voice Control for Ubuntu 12.04

I think, **Gnome-Voice-Control** is not in the repositories ("Unable to locate package gnome-voice-control"). And as you can see [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-voice-control) and [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Attic/GnomeVoiceControl) **it is not longer developed**.

If you would like to make and use your own voice commands ("*Update system now*") try [Simon listens](http://www.simon-listens.org/index.php?id=122&L=1).

#### Simon Listens

Installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:grasch-simon-listens/simon
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install simon
```

In Simon, for example, you can record a command and link it to a *bash-script* doing what you want or link it to *DBUS-commands*. In this way it is very easy to create any voice command! I tried it and it works fine. The more you train your Speech-commands, the better it understands your commands after that.

- [Youtube Video about Simon Listens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjJCl72f-Gs)
- [Blog about Simon Listens](http://simon-listens.blogspot.de/)
- [Documentation](http://userbase.kde.org/Simon)

[image: Screenshot]

Alternatively try [VEDICS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vedics/). But, until now, it can handle only one (?) command.

Comment: has anyone ever gotten simon listens working on anything other than kde???

Answer (score 1):

### [Mycroft Core](https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-core)

I couldn't get the Plasmoid widget to install on Kubuntu 18.10, but I am working on basic utility functions through CLI. So far have that working, and I am [writing a skill](https://github.com/MycroftAI/mycroft-skills/issues/1341) to use Xdotool commands.

Mycroft by default [uses Google's STT engine](https://mycroft-ai.gitbook.io/docs/using-mycroft-ai/customizations/stt-engine#default-enginehttps://mycroft-ai.gitbook.io/docs/using-mycroft-ai/customizations/stt-engine#default-engine).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install simon on Elementary, and got this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 simon : Depends: libattica0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I downloaded the following package:
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/43721319/libattica0_0.1.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

and installed it with:

```
sudo dpkg -i ./libattica0_0.1.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

and that solved the issue :)